# How can I store variable having high range in C program?

Tags: c, variables, integer

Suppose I want to store variable having datatype integer.
Integer provide certain range 2 byte or 4 byte.
Also range of -32768 to 32767.
I want to store 32768.
How can I?

Comment: 16-bit unsigned integer has range 0-65536.

Comment: Use long or unsigned int.

Comment: Or use whatever type gives you a 32-bit integer (signed or unsigned).

Comment: A 4-byte `int` has the range `-2147483648  to  2147483647` and `unsigned` has the range `0  to  4294967295`

Comment: use standard types and `int32_t`

Answer (score 1):

On different platforms, `int`s are different sizes in C. Sometimes, like you said, they are 2 bytes, and sometimes they are 4, etc. So if it's 2 bytes, that's 16 bits, so it can store 2^16 = 65536 different values. Since you're using a signed value, half these values are negative, so that's why you can't put in a bigger value for an `int` here. However, if you're using C99 or later, you could use `int32_t` by including `stdint.h`.  This will allow you to store up to 2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 0):

There is a data type that is guaranteed to hold that range in *all C implementations*. It is called `long int`. Perhaps use that one instead.

Additionally 32-bit platforms will usually have it 32-bit; the only difference here is 64-bit platforms where some might use a 64-bit datatype for it.

If storage requirements are important, use `int32_t`.